# Datadog: kafka.messages_in.rate kafka metirc meaning

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, datadog

Does ***kafka.messages_in.rate*** represents the number of events from producer to broker or it also includes the replication events from other brokers. The official doc is useless just presents the same metric in plain English without an possible explanation

Comment: what do you mean by replication events from other brokers ? in Kafka we may have n no.of brokers, but leader is going to be only one, he is responsible for writing replication to remaining  brokers.

Comment: Will the replication messages from leader to the follower is also counted for kafka.messages_in.rate

Answer (score -1):

It only applies to produce requests.